# Get the loaded page in jQuery Mobile 1.4.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm used to the older jQuery Mobile interface where I could write:

```
$("#page").on("pageLoad", function(){
    //Do something
});
```

With the newer pageContainer widget and it's events, I do not know to do detect what page was loaded.

For example, I need to know how to detect that the `#settings` page was just loaded. So far I can figure out

```
$("body").on( "pagecontainerload", function( event, ui ){});
```

but I have no way of knowing what page was loaded. I've tried using the returned event and ui values but without success.

It seems part of my problem is coming from improper use of

```
$("body").pagecontainer("load", "welcome.html");
```

I use that in the beginning of my js file to load them all into the DOM. However, when I navigate to that page, then away from it again it is removed from the DOM. For example, I load welcome.html, settings.html, and devices.html with the above code. Then, I have links like

```
<a href="#settings" class="navigation" data-icon="gear" data-transition="slide">Settings</a>
```

And when I use that link to go to the settings page, then another of the same kind of link to go to the devices page, the settings link no longer works. Upon inspecting the DOM, #settings has been removed. Infact, so has #welcome. As soon as I navigate away from that `page` it is removed from the DOM. So either I have done something wrong, or my understanding of the pagecontainer widget is flawed.

Comment: http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/jquery-mobile-page-events-extra/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Based on your updated OP, *external pages* are removed once you navigate away from them, this is the default behavior of jQM. If you want to keep those pages, you need to add `data-dom-cache="true"` to page div of each *external page*.

You can retrieve *page* loaded from `ui` object emitted on `pagecontainerload`.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerload", function (e, ui) {
  var loadedPage = $(ui.page),
      pageID = loadedPage[0].id;

  if (pageID == "settings") {
    /* code */
  }
});
```

Note that `pagecontainerbeforeload`, `pagecontainerload` and `pagecontainerfail`, are only emitted on pages loaded *externaly*. Moreover, they will fire everytime an *external* page is loaded, unless *DOM cache is enabled*. Read more about those events [here](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/jquery-mobile-page-events-extra/).

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/DUFw4/)**

Comment: Hi @user3669154 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: The pages are external files, but are then pre-loaded, after that they are changed via `#links`, what would be the best way to detect that kind of page change?

Comment: @user3669154 you mean pre-fetched?

Comment: I mean this: $("body").pagecontainer("load", "welcome.html");

Comment: They will fire if you `load` any external page. Check the demo, click on "load button", this loads page programmatically. The code in demo is comprehensive, let me know if you need further explanation. @user3669154

Comment: @Omar It looks like my problem is that I'm not using load properly. I was using it like PHP's include which is not correct I don't think. I need all pages in one file so that all of the js variables stay the same. Though I think I can pass those with page changes. The only reason there are physical files is for the readability

Comment: @user3669154 the events wont work loading them by PHP. in that case, you need `pagecreate`. http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/

Comment: @Omar I'm not using PHP. I was likening the $("body").pagecontainer("load", "welcome.html"); to include("welcome.html"); as would be used in PHP. My point is that I don't think pagecontainer load works that way.

Comment: @user3669154 `$("body").pagecontainer("load", "welcome.html");` should work. If you're facing any issues with `load`, post more details in your question.

Comment: @Omar I updated my question to include more details about my loading issue.